# What is the list of softwares on the Visual Studio splash screen?

Tags: visual-studio, splash-screen

What is the list of softwares that is displayed on the splash screen when you start Visual Studio.
I dont think those are the softwares that are installed because I have seen some softwares on that list(like resharper 4.5) but don't see the software anywhere on my machine/start menu/Add Remove Programs/ VS SDK GUI.
I find that odd....Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the "installed products" for Visual Studio.

It's up to each product whether it wishes to display an icon on the splash screen or not. You can view the list of Installed products via Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio. If there are icons showing for products which are no longer installed on your machine, it may indicate some form of corruption in the product registration system for Visual Studio.

---

If you're writing your own Visual Studio Package, you control your appearance on the splash screen via the `UseInterface` property of the `InstalledProductRegistrationAttribute` attribute, and implement the `IVsInstalledProduct` interface